# argparse type validation for nargs input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm using python 3.74 and I'm trying to use the argparse module to read a pair of numbers into the variable `nums`. I would like to check if certain conditions hold between the two numbers and then sort them.

I have the code below.

```
import argparse

def f(x):
   assert x[0]!=x[1],"err"
   return sorted([int(y) for y in x])

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--nums", required=True, type=f,nargs=2)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I want the snippet above to return `[1, 2]` when the input is `2 1`. I get an IndexError instead.

This led me to investigate with the code below:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--nums", required=True, type=lambda x:x*2 ,nargs=2)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

now the output for `2 1` is `['22', '11']`
which leads me to believe that type is applied te each of the values separately. Is there any way to perform type validation on --nums as a whole? I'd preferably like to do it within add_argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) states

> `type=` can take any callable that takes a single string argument and returns the converted value

And we can confirm this by looking at the [ArgParse implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py#L2462), `nargs` arguments are evaluated individually. So your `f` function is being called for each argument.

If you really want it to be done as part of the type checking, you could require a string input of `1,2` and parse that yourself like so:

```py
def f(x):
    x = x.split(',')
    assert x[0]!=x[1],'err'
    return sorted([int(y) for y in x])
```

Where an input of `1,2` results in `[1, 2]`

But that defeats the purpose of argparse, so you're better off simply calling your validator after the arguments have been parsed, the experience for the end-user is no different.

```py
parser.add_argument("--nums", required=True, type=int, nargs=2)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(f(args.nums))
```

An input of `2 1` returns `[1, 2]`

Comment: Thanks. I don't see how this defeats the purpose of argparse though. Any validation can be done outside of argparse so why shouldn't we be able to perform this specific kind inside argparse? A use case I could see is constructing any object that requires more than one input value (ie a circle type requiring x,y coordinates and a nonnegative radius, complex numbers, etc.).

Comment: I said that because argparse already has `nargs` which covers the use case of `x,y`. It's also a standard that end-users are used to, so it's better to utilise the tools at hand :)

Comment: The example I posted does include `nargs`

Comment: Yes but it cannot be used how you're trying to, I'm saying you can force your own method by splitting a string and validating that rather than relying on nargs, but that defeats its purpose. Regardless, I believe my answer is still correct :)

Comment: I see what you mean now. It'd be nice if validation could be performed on all the values passed into an argument simultaneously :/